# Nintex forms 2013 not working with Custom Master Page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I am using custom master page and installed the nintex forms 2013 in my sharepoint 2013 environment.

When I click on any New Item which contains the Nintex form getting below error.

> The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.

Comment: We would need some more information. What is special about your custom MasterPage? Apparently you have some code behind or custom controls on the page? Nintex doesn't really care about the MasterPage. You should also try asking your question on Nintex Connect as Stackoverflow is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed It...

Open custom master html file...

get this from header:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Cut it out...

go to the body part... find div with the id "s4-workspace" and paste the code before this div like this:

```
[...]
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<div id="s4-workspace" class="s4-nosetwidth">
[...]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved my issue too

I would love to mention that I don't have Nintex , but i have Ajax in my pages , and for some reason I've been getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Support confirmed that this snippet belongs in the body.

It's put in the head by the code generated to produce a Minimal Master page, and that's confirmed as a bug.